# getdevice id IMEI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-permissions

How can I get device IMEI
I've tried getdeviceid() but android studio says its deprecated

```
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
     defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.notification.aldiccp"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

I've tried getdeviceid() on 5.1.1 device it works fine but on 6.0 its not
other question how can i use Runtime permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Need permission To request Device Id if you target 23 and higher to make permissin easly you can use this library very useful

[Dexter](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter)